# use tag is not working when created dynamically through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to create SVG  tags dynamically through Javascript because I am going to use a bunch of them in my HTML but when they get created the image(which is coming from href="the id of another SVG" of the use tag ) is not appearing.
Can anyone tell me that what's going on and how to fix that?

Here is the code (when you run the code you will see empty blue boxes start creating and they are the newly SVG tags and I have appended the use tag to these SVG tags but the use tag is not working (means not sowing the image)).

```js
function test(){
 setTimeout(()=>{
     //let a = document.createElement("svg");
       var a = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

  a.classList.add("newbee");
   let use = document.createElement("use") 
   use.setAttribute("href","#theBee")
   use.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 62.4 38.4 ")
   use.setAttribute("class","corr-p-3 bee")
   use.setAttribute("width","62.4")
   use.setAttribute("height","38.4")
   use.setAttribute("x","0")
   use.setAttribute("y","0")
   let  c =  a.appendChild(use)
   console.log(a)

  let check = document.body.appendChild(a);
    

   test()
 },Math.floor(Math.random() * (6000 - 3000 + 1) ) + 3000)
}

test()
```

```css
.newbee{
  border:2px solid blue;
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="hero-svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 50 630 630" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <symbol id="theBee" viewBox="0 0 78 49">
      <g id="complete_bee">
        <path id="bee head" d="M11.553 35.5047C16.3904 38.8245 21.8681 37.8364 24.0023 36.4532V15.1115C22.9352 14.4397 19.5917 13.499 14.7542 15.1115C9.9168 16.724 8.37329 20.5655 7.99604 21.7512C6.88944 25.2291 6.71554 32.1848 11.553 35.5047Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
        <circle id="bee eye" cx="15.532" cy="21.6908" r="2.96412" fill="#313131" />
        <path id="bee trunk" d="M65.8034 15.1697C45.3154 7.5816 30.1154 12.008 23.9501 15.1697V36.6299C37.3242 43.649 56.6739 38.0527 64.1435 34.3772C78.0156 27.5513 77.7785 19.6049 65.8034 15.1697Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
        <path id="trunk lines" d="M32.961 12.087C30.4711 16.1577 26.9142 26.5519 32.3682 39.3569L35.8065 39.8312C29.8309 27.5004 34.2652 15.5649 36.7551 11.4942L32.961 12.087Z" fill="#4E4E4E" stroke="black" />
        <path id="trunk lines_2" d="M42.9204 39.8312C36.9447 27.5005 41.2605 15.0907 43.7503 11.02L47.7815 11.1385C45.2917 15.2092 40.5017 27.1448 46.4773 39.4755L42.9204 39.8312Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
        <path id="trunk lines_3" d="M53.947 38.0527C47.2667 27.313 51.8749 15.6325 54.6584 12.087L58.3339 12.7984C55.5504 16.3439 50.8236 26.246 57.504 36.9856L53.947 38.0527Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
        <path id="trunk lines_4" d="M63.7528 34.6143C56.6849 26.8661 61.298 16.5925 64.38 14.6955L67.5819 15.8811C65.3292 18.6081 61.4051 23.9435 66.3963 33.1916L63.7528 34.6143Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />

        <path class="small-wing" d="M61.4166 1.06052C55.8203 0.206853 39.1659 8.60919 32.6053 12.0871C54.3264 11.3283 59.9938 9.00435 61.4166 8.05583C63.2303 6.8467 67.0128 1.91419 61.4166 1.06052Z" fill="#99CEFF" stroke="black" />

        <path class="large-wing" d="M32.9609 11.9685C48.0977 7.26541 80.3166 -2.14073 74.6957 7.34446C68.7675 14.5769 44.3036 13.6679 32.9609 11.9685Z" fill="#81D1FE" stroke="black" />
        <path id="bee sting" d="M70.4275 30.7017L73.273 27.7376L76 32.7173L70.4275 30.7017Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />

        <path id="antenna" d="M13.1606 15.8811C13.4768 12.6008 12.1173 5.73197 4.14972 4.4989M10.3151 17.8967C9.36656 14.4583 6.09418 8.05584 0.592773 9.95288" stroke="black" />
        <path id="bee legs" d="M30.3525 39.1198L26.2028 43.151L28.2184 46.2337M35.6879 39.9497L31.7753 44.5738L34.2652 48.605" stroke="black" />
        <circle id="antenna ball" cx="4.38689" cy="4.38033" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
        <circle id="antenna ball_2" cx="0.592824" cy="9.83431" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
        <path id="bee behind legs" d="M49.2044 39.2384L45.6475 43.6253L47.6631 45.9965M55.4883 37.8156L50.8643 43.6253L55.4883 46.8265" stroke="black" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
  
  </svg>
  
  
  
<svg class="newbee">
    <use href="#theBee" class="corr-p-3 bee" width="62.4" height="38.4" x="0" y="0"/>
</svg>
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead of `createElement`

Comment: @enxaneta I tried this But it's not working.  I think you have answered my another SVG-related question. So if this trick is not working what should I do.  and if this question seems useful you can upvote this.

Comment: @RobertLongson I didn't get that  can you tell me how

Comment: @RobertLongson I get your point, Yes it starts working Thanks for this answer you can write your comment in the answer form. I will upvote this and accept your answer. if this question seems useful you can upvote this.  and can you make me understand what the createElementNS does. Is it different from createElement?